# Feeding commands to WinSCP

Tags: java, runtime.exec, winscp

I have Java Code that launch process of WinSCP tool and connects to a Unix machine and then call a xxxx.exe located on the Unix machine.

The problem is that xxxx.exe accepts a parameter of a type File. So I need to upload this to the remote machine and then passed to the xxxx.exe.... that is failing
and I'm trying to avoid the temporary folders as possible.

small Code

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rTool\\WinSCP.com /script=folder\\code.txt < C:\\FILESTOUPLOADS\\upload1.txt" );
```

The login information goes in `code.txt` as supported by `WinSCP.com`

Comment: What is the right syntex to uplad a file and pass it as parameter ? ie in the 
rTool\\WinSCP.com /script=folder\\code.txt < C:\\FILESTOUPLOADS\\upload1.txt

Comment: Would it not be more intersting to search for a good way to transfer your file to the server, instead of calling an external program?

Comment: .exe on linux machine ??

Comment: The single line invocation of `Runtime.exec()` rarely works.  Follow the recommendations of the article linked from the [Runtime.exec info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) before wondering too much why it breaks.  Also, use a `ProcessBuilder` for 1.5+, and break the arguments into a `String[]`

Answer (score 1):

file redirection (i.e. the "<" symbol) is handled my the command processor, which `Runtime.exec()` does not use.  As mentioned in comments already, first use the String[] version of exec so that you don't have issues with command parsing.  second, you need to invoke the command processor to handle the file redirection (e.g. using "cmd.exe /k"), or [handle it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969766/process-requires-redirected-input) in java.

Comment: thank you for your replies .. but i still want the execution to be done in the remote machine . Im still need to use this extrnal  tool winSCP because it allows me to have the login remotely ..

Comment: jtahlborn: I've done this way it's woks for passing the file as parameter after transfer the file via Socket. but also i need to pass another parameter how the syntax of ProcessBuilder will be in tow parameter one of them is File and the other is string

Comment: @Gerard - add more elements to your String[]?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `ProcessBuilder`  to change working directory and set path of the file from that directory

> public ProcessBuilder directory(File directory)Sets this process builder's working directory. Subprocesses subsequently started by this object's start() method will use this as their working directory. The argument may be null -- this means to use the working directory of the current Java process, usually the directory named by the system property user.dir, as the working directory of the child process.
>
> Parameters:
>   directory - The new working directory 
>   Returns:
>   This process builder

Comment: How does this get the file onto the remote server?